# UI elements not showing on Xcode

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When I click the '+' sign - it is meant to show UI elements such as Buttons, Slider etc.

But sometimes it doesn't show and I don't know how to fix it. See below:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI elements (as well as SwiftUI menu items in context menu) are shown *only* when Preview Canvas is opened.

[image: demo]

In your case, as seen, Canvas is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Open Canvas with your editor then you will get the UI controls view.

Answer (score 1):

To add to my fellow helpers, here's where you find the canvas on/off :

[image]